# What to do about "here my solution to coding competition in another language"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176777/codility-equilibrium-index-sample-test-my-stab-at-it) that asks why some java code fails some online coding competition.

It was solved; and the question even protected later on; but still it has like 30 answers by now, because **a lot** of people just dump their version of the solution in their favorite language there.

Maybe I am naive, but I am kinda wondering ... wtf?

Edit: would it be reasonable for example to **fully** protect such questions, to avoid *any* kind of later answer?

Comment: The question looks like it's from code review, but the answers make it look like code golf... interesting case

Comment: So many "code-only" answers ... I guess that's the quality this site is all about :P. Too bad, that they aren't able to be flagged as VLQ and spenting ~20 rep points for them .. :/

Comment: If the non java answers get downvoted to negative territory we can vote to delete them and your rep will be refunded. Though frankly at 28K it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: To avoid any new answers being added, the question could be closed as Off-topic (Code Review) or Too Broad.

Comment: @MartinSmith Does one have to use a smiley all the time so that people understand when one is not really serious? Anyway, I think we are on a good way here ...

Comment: Yes, you need to use a smiley *every* time you are not serious.  Humour is *very* hard to intuit online (particularly for non-native English speakers).

Comment: And especially when the "humour" is just a statement that can be taken at face value. IIRC it said something like you don't like to spend on downvotes more rep than you receive on upvotes in any one particular day.

Comment: I've downvoted almost all of the answers, Java or no, as very few of them actually acknowledge that there's an OP asking a question about their attempted solution. Most of them are just people posting their attempts at the problem. They don't tell the OP how to improve their code.

Comment: Only one answer remaining: [Codility equilibrium index sample test - my stab at it](//stackoverflow.com/a/38740221). Good thing is that every deleted anwer has a comment explaining why it isn't appropriate.

Comment: Despite the slew of poor answers, the question is a good one. I don't agree with it being closed.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Some answerers have more than 10 reputation - that means closure is the only way to fully prevent crap answers from coming in. That said, closing with the custom off-topic reason "This is actually an acceptable question, but it needs to be closed because it attracted poor answers from users who can answer protected questions" would be more appropriate IMO.

Comment: I don't think that's appropriate either, @dor. That's an abuse of the closure system, just because some people don't know how to read the question. The correct solution is just to delete the answers, as we've done. Sometimes Meta is regretfully necessary for successful moderation.

Comment: Somebody around who wants to put up an answer with the "consensus" that has been reached here?

Comment: This question was protected! How come answers continued to pour in? I was under the impression that if a question is protected, further answers are disallowed. :-?

Comment: @Abhitalks It was protected from answers fro users with < 10 reputation.

Comment: @Abhitalks: The only thing that stops more answers from any user is closure. Protection, as mentioned, just requires 10 rep earned on the site to answer.

Comment: @GhostCat: Oops! I don't know what I was thinking when I protected it an year ago. I should've closed it as well.

Comment: @Abhitalks On the other hand, as you can see, people are not in 100% agreement if "closing" is really appropriate either.

Comment: Seems like a good fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's "too broad" for sure.

Comment: For some reason, I see two answers, not thirty...

Comment: Because they got all downvoted and then deleted. That can happen when several users with enough reputation  start working such sinks of low quality answers. Remember to turn back here when you reached 10k rep then you can see them all. You know, I can see dead postings!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree with the WTF part; it's unusual to have so *many* pointless answers. I guess this question was linked to from some popular blog or something.

As people noted in comments, to prevent *anyone* from posting an answer, just close the question. However, if there is no reason to close the question, don't do anything - just vote "-1" for bad answers or vote to "delete" the non-answers.

---

Coding competition questions are often off-topic (too broad) here, because the competition sites provide no debugging feedback, and the OP doesn't bother providing any diagnostics. So the question is usually

> Here is my code. The competition site told me it's bad. Please help.

However, this specific question is a little better than average. It asks

> However the code fails because it fails a few complex arrays and does not scale well.

Here, you can answer at least the "does not scale" question. So the question should not be closed.