# Typo which leads to a very interesting analysis

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41745877/2805305) has what most likely is a typo. A `<<` instead of a `;`. However the implications of this typo are far from trivial. The incorrect code compiles without a problem and produces a seemingly unexpected output.

The explanation of what happens is very interesting and involves a analysis of the evolution of C++, the motivation of such changes, and reveals a compiler bug.

The post has been closed as a "typographical error" and reopened multiple times now.

My view is that it should stay opened. I would think that the 
"typo close" reason is intended for silly typos that answers would not bring any value to the site, other than "You have this typo. Fix it and you're good. Not much to tell here". In that case yes, a close is perfectly justified. This is not such a case, even if the underlying cause is a typo. The answer **is interesting**, as proof by the excellent accepted answer with over 100 votes.

So I think that we need to reach a conclusion of whether to close the question or not and maybe lock it (due to multiple close/open cycles it has gone through in 3 days alone).

My vote is to leave it open.

Comment: I've locked the post temporarily to avoid a meta effect. Let's see whether to make this permanent or what when this topic is settled.

Comment: The main question that pops in my mind: is there a way to format the Q AWAY from the typo and more into the actual analysis? i get your point... But I don't think a lot of other users would find that Q if it really is phrased around the typo,no?

Comment: @Patrice Removing "I am completely new to C++" would be a start.

Comment: @totzam that is useless fluff, yes. Doesn't do much to make the Q about the behavior and not the typo though....

Comment: The answer is indeed interesting. The bug was not his obvious.
But I don't see how people will find this question! I vote for open if the question is heavily edited to be usefull and searchable. If no edit is made to the question . I just don't vote.

Comment: I don't see the ".. excellent **accepted** answer" ...

Comment: Indication that the person asking the question is completely new to the language is *not* "useless fluff", @patrice. It suggests to a prospective answerer what they can reasonably assume about the person's background knowledge. Now, obviously a full diatribe about the asker's level of experience is useless and should be edited out. But it is overzealous to remove a simple indication that someone is a novice with regards to the language under discussion. It's not like the question is too long as it stands.

Comment: @Patrice: The entire premise of the question is of the mistakenly placed << resulting in the unexpected output. No one in their right mind would deliberately arrange the symbols, literals, tokens and line breaks in that manner, and ask why the code behaves that way. So no, you can't format the question in such a way as to deemphasize the typo, because the typo is the *essence* of the question.

Comment: Why 'community' has reopened the question? Was it automatic?

Comment: @veve Community didn't reopen it, it just unlocked it. deceze applied a moderator lock, which ages away after a certain period of time. Community unlocked it after the "content dispute" lock expired. It was reopened by 5 community members, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41745877/revisions). Its now on the verge of being closed again by 4 community members. Sigh.

Comment: @CodyGray so... what is the nex step? The upvotes on your answer show that the question should not be closed and not edited either. Can we consider this the consensus? Should a mod close the question for closing... should we edit the question to stay it shouldn't be closed... So yeah, I don't have exp here on meta. What's next now?

Comment: There's no way to prevent a question from being closed, other than locking it. Although consensus can be established on Meta regarding whether or not a question should be closed, there's no real way to enforce it. Even a permanent lock is no good—the question is honestly better off closed than locked because at least the existing answers can be edited. I have no idea what the next step is.

Comment: @CodyGray I've added a footnote on the question. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: @GodyGray thanks for the explaination, I didn't knew about the automatic unlocking of the moderator lock.

Comment: I'd say the original question would benefit from "this is likely a typo, I know about this" style comment next to place where the typo likely happened. This would likely reduce the "typo close vote" temptation.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Closing this as a "typo" question is nonsensical. The question doesn't ask you to debug the code or explain how to fix it. Rather, it asks *why* the code does what it does. That's a perfectly valid question, regardless of whether or not the problem arose as a result of a typo.

In fact, closing this question *at all* is nonsensical. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the question. It's clearly presented, it gives a nice, short MCVE, and it shows the actual output that is produced. The only thing that would make it better would be to indicate the *expected* output, but that's really picking nits, because I think it's pretty obvious that someone would expect 2+3 to produce an output of 5.

Frankly, I don't think the question is that interesting. But "uninteresting" isn't a reason to close questions (just downvote them), so this question should not be closed.

There's also no compelling reason to close the question to prevent answers. Although this is technically an abuse of the closing system as far as I'm concerned, [there is sometimes a motivation to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342015/what-to-do-about-here-my-solution-to-coding-competition-in-another-language). That isn't a problem here. It has received a reasonable number of answers, each adding information that is not contained in one of the other answers. (Well, full disclosure: there was one short, duplicate answer posted, but that was deleted by the action of 3 20k+ reputation users, within a few hours of it being posted. Moderation *does* work.)

Comment: The one other thing the question could use is the specific compiler (and version) that was used.

Comment: Why would that matter, @pokechu? Do you think this behavior is specific to a particular compiler version? I'd actually say that would be a *bad* thing to include, since what makes the answers most useful is that they refer to the language standard, which is universal and applies to all compilers/vendors.

Comment: Because from what I can tell, [it does behave differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745877/why-does-cout-print-2-3-15-in-this-snippet-of-code#comment70685137_41745877) across compilers/versions of the standard/whatever.  (I don't use C++ too much, so I'm not sure of the specific information that would be helpful, but as far as I can tell from reading the comments it _isn't_ necessarily reproducible with just the information in the question).

Comment: Hmm yeah. What actually needs to be specified is the version of the C++ standard being used (e.g., C++03, C++11, C++14, etc.). The version of the *compiler* is not especially important. But as it stands now, the answers address all of the standards, which is actually ideal from my perspective—it makes the Q&A more general and more useful.

Comment: In response to your 2nd paragraph, typo questions can also easily meet all those criteria. So what is your bar for closing a question as typo?

Comment: @barry See the first paragraph. If the question is asking you to debug code, and the problem with that code is a typo, then it should be closed.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, but I think most people would consider "because you wrote `<<` instead of `;`" a perfectly valid answer to "Why does it print 15?" It's not a focused question on why `cout << cout;` prints 1, per bolov's [suggested rewording](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342117/2069064).

Comment: @Barry: That would be an answer to "why doesn't it print 5?". An answer to why it prints 15 has to explain where the 1 comes from and just saying "<< instead of ;" may point at the reason but doesn't explain it. That's my view anyway but would have expected coders to be more precise about things. :)

Answer (score 15):

Based on the first comments it seems that the problem is that even if the answer is indeed interesting, the question in is current form is not "searchable" and thus not useful.

So I suggest the following edit to the question in order to make it relevant:

> #### Strange output with cout << cout
>
> I compiled this code by accident:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main(){
>     cout << "2+3 = " <<
>     cout << 2 + 3 << endl;
> }
> ```
>
> To my surprise it compiled and the output was
>
> ```
> 2+3=15
> ```
>
> What is the reason why `cout` itself is allowed on the right side of a `cout <<`
> operator call and what is the explanation of the output?

Comment: If the question is rephrased like this, all the answers will need to be fixed as well, since the original question stemmed from the fact that the OP didn't realize the program was in essence printing `cout << cout`, and that's what most of the answers address. Also, what's missing from here is the expected output. I still think is should say somewhere "Why is it printing `2+3=15` instead of `2+3=5`?".

Comment: I think the existing answers would still be understandable in the new context. They all _mention_ the mistake, but they also all address the more interesting `cout << cout` part.